# Explain concept of size of integer,character and float pointer in GCC

Tags: pointers, gcc

In GCC(Ubuntu 12 .04) Following code is the program which i need to understand for the concept of size of integer,character and float pointer.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    main()
    {
         int i=20,*p;
         char ch='a',*cp;
         float f=22.3,*fp;
         printf("%d %d %d\n",sizeof(p),sizeof(cp),sizeof(fp));
         printf("%d %d %d\n",sizeof(*p),sizeof(*cp),sizeof(*fp));
     }
```

Here i am getting following output when i run the above code in "UBUNTU 12.04" 
Output:

```
    8 8 8
    4 1 4
```

As per this lines,"Irrespective of data types,size of pointer for address it will allow 4 bytes BY DEFAULT"
Then what is the reason behind getting sizeof(p)=8 instead it should be sizeof(p)=4....
Please explain me.

Comment: A pointer on a 64bit-system is usually 64bit (=8Byte). 4Byte is 32bit.

Comment: The size of a pointer is platform-dependent. But generally, 32-bit software has 4-byte pointers, and 64-bit software has 8-byte ones.

Comment: @Cameron Thank you...So that means the size of pointer varies as per 32-bit and 64-bit software?? Your answer is specific and helped me a lot.

Comment: @Muskaan: Yes, it varies depending in your hardware, operating system, user software. 64bit, 32bit, (16bit)...there are more exotic computers too, but that won´t matter here. (Btw., what is my comment missing?)

Answer (score 5):

sizeof(x) will return the size of x. A pointer is like any other variable, except that it holds an address. On your 64 bit machine, the pointer takes 64 bits or 8 bytes, and that is what sizeof will return. All pointers on your machine will be 8 bytes long, *regardless* of what data they point to.

The data they *point to* may be of a different length.

```
int x = 5; // x is a 32 bit int, takes up 4 bytes
int *y = &x; // y holds the address of x, & is 8 bytes
float *z; // z holds the address of a float, and an address is still 8 bytes long
```

You're probably getting confused because you previously have done this on a 32 bit computer. You see, the 32 / 64 bit indicates the size of a machine address. So, on a 32 bit computer, a pointer holds an address that is at most 32 bits long, or four bytes. Your current machine must be a 64 bit machine, which is why the pointer needs to be 8 bytes long.

Read more about this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit).

Heck, it's not just the address length. The size of other data types is also platform AND implementation dependent. For example, an int may be 16 bits on one platform & 32 bits on another. A third implementation might go crazy and have 128 bit ints. The only guarantee in the spec is that an int will be at least 16 bits long. When in doubt, always check. The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) page on C data types would be helpful.

Comment: Okay now i am clear..Thanks...Your answer helped me.. :)

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(p)` will return an *address*, and you are most likely running on a 64-bit machine, so your addresses will be `(8*8)` or `64` bits in length.

The size of the value *dereferenced* by `p` is a `32` bit integer `(4*8)`.

You can verify this by seeing that all:

- All pointers have `sizeof` as 8
- Your char value is size 1 (typical of many implementations of c)
- Print `p` and `*p` (for all variables). You will see the actual address length this way.

Comment: So that means the size of pointer varies for 32-bit and 64-bit machine..So that means the value of 4-byte and 8-byte both are correct as per 32-bit and 64-bit respectively?Am i clear?

Comment: @Muskaan for a 32-bit machine, the 32 means the address size in bits. In this scenario, the 32 bits have nothing to do with the address size but instead represent the size of the actual integer, meaning it can have values 2^31 - 2^31 -1. Very important to make the distinction between size of an address, and size of an actual piece of data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which documentation you're using but my guess is that they're talking about pointers in 32bit.
In 64 bit the size of a pointer becomes 8 bytes